# Android: set orientation programmatically takes time until layout actually changes

Tags: java, android, orientation

When I call to:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

it takes 2-3 seconds until the layout is actually changes on the screen.

The question is, is there some event or property which I can get the information that the layout was changed on the screen? When I getting the property with:

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

it's already set to the new orientation. But the actual view on screen is in the old orientation. It changes 2-3 seconds after.
(Also tried the screen width and height ratio, same as orientation).

So, is there a way to detect once the layout actually is changed on screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    import android.content.res.Configuration;

      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
  {

         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
         //

  }
```

Comment: same effect. the event is called and finished, and only after 2-3 seconds the layout is changed on screen